# How to change file type in textmate

Tags: textmate

It will give you a selection when you open a new file in Textmate. It asks you what the file type is and let you select a grammar for the new file.

So how to change the file grammar after I selecting the grammar once?

Answer (score 28):

There's a button on the bottom bar.

[image: collapsed menu]

You press it, and there they are, all possible syntax modes with their shortcuts:

[image: expanded menu]