# Textmate 2 + Rails 4 : no shortcuts for ruby tags in application.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, textmate2

In Textmate 2, my shortcuts for ruby tags don't work on the `application.html.erb`file.  It works on all the other views.`enter code here` Also, I don't have color coding for my css on the css.scss pages.  Is this due to TM2 still in beta, or are there fixes for these?

Answer (score 0):

You have to manage bundles by yourself. Sad but true. I successfully made this work only after installing TM form scratch and installing SASS/SCSS bundles manually.

Comment: That didn't work for me either, but there was a menu at the bottom of the page, I had to change to "HTML (Ruby-ERB)" and that did the trick! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099383/how-to-change-file-type-in-textmate